# How to create anonymous object from T?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, anonymous-methods

I have GetEntities method in EF context. In some cases I don't want to load all properties of entities in memory. I want to load only 'selected' properties. I'm using anonymous object for getting only special properties. For example, I have Product entity and I'm getting only Name and Cost properties (ONLY FOR READING).

```
context.GetEntities<Product>().Select(a => new { a.Name,a.Cost }).ToList();
```

I'm using it in many places. So, I created PropertyNames collection and I want to create GetEntities method which gets entities with these properties:

```
 public object GetEntities<T>(IEnumerable<string> proeprtyNames) 
 {
     return //anonymous entities which have only proeprtyNames properties
 }
```

How to create this method? And also I don't know what should be return type of method

Comment: You can't define an anonymous type as the return type. You may be able to return a dynamic type, but it's not really type safe programming. I think you should just write this code directly in your logic, this method doesn't really save you anything.

Comment: I wouldn't go about it the way you intent. However to make it work, you should look into System.Reflection. There you can access properties as a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** You need to create a repository to accept your `TEntity` as a generic class entity and in that repository, you have to create one method that can retrieve only those columns from the database table that you're specified in `Select` expression predicate.

```
public class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<TResult> GetEntities<TResult>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> selector) where TResult : class
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Select(selector).ToList();
    }
}
```

**2)** And then while using above repository, you can pass only those properties from your `Product` entity those you want to retrieve like

```
Repository<Product> repository = new Repository<Product>(new MySqlDbContext());

var anonymousResultSet = repository.GetEntities(x => new { x.Name, x.Cost });  //<= Here you can specify those columns that you want to retrieve.

return anonymousResultSet;
```

Comment: How can I get another entities?

Comment: Not getting what you want to say?

Comment: I can't use Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> selector in parameter. I have only string collection. Look at GetEntities method above

Comment: if your property names are in strings then you need a reflection because you need to tell the compiler which property name is mapped with entity property. I think its tedious task to do this. I suggest you to go through my answer because repository pattern is more flexible and suitable in most cases.

Comment: What happens? Did you face any problem now?

Comment: As said by **Mike** above, you really need to use reflection to work as you intended because compiler won't know about your strings property names and reflection is quite heavy to do your work. So try as my way you found that its really helpful and most of developer prefer this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Repository pattern](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/getting-started-with-repository-pattern-using-C-Sharp/) for this issue.

Create `Repository` class like ;

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public Repository(DBContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _dbSet = dbContext.Set<T>();
    }


    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbSet;
    }
}
```

and your function can be

```
 public object GetEntities<T>() 
 {
     using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
     {
            Repository<T> repository = new Repository<T>(db);
            list = repository.GetAll();
            return list.ToList();
     }
 }
```